# circle cuts $y=x^3-25x$ in six points

Tags: geometry

Prove that if a circle cuts $y=x^3-25x$ in six points  $(x_i; y_i)$, 1≤i≤6 then sum  $x_1+x_2+...+x_6$  does not depend on radius and center.
I can't imagine a draw.

[image]

(picture added by jeanmarie)

Comment: I have added a picture.

Answer (score 3):

The circle is
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2-r^2=0.$$
Substituting $x^3-25x$ for $y$ gives a sextic for $x$. The sum of
its roots will be the negative of its $x^5$-coefficient. What is that?